# How to get customer id , customer firstname with customer_account_edited event ? Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

event.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_edited">
        <observer name="customer_customer_account_edited" instance="Customer\CustomerAccountEdit\Observer\CustomerAccountEdit"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

CustomerAccountEdit.php

```
<?php
namespace Customer\CustomerAccountEdit\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class CustomerAccountEdit implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $_customerGroup;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        $id = $customer->getId();
        print_r($customer->debug());
    }
}
```

Result.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getEmail() on null in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getData()` method to get email

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent();
$email=$customer->getData('email');
```

Updated answer:

```
$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($email);
$userId = $CustomerModel->getId();
```

**Note: Code Tested**

Comment: it works, but i can't get customer id, first name and last name through this , thanks MSA

Comment: You can get name by load customer collection by  email id

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I think that objectmanager places are best injected in the class \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer

Comment: Yes, You can use Di method(Injection in a constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is correct however using object manager.

Better practice is to use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function getCustomerByEmail($email)
    {
        try{
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
        }catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $exception){
            // handle this
        }catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $exception){
            // handle this
        }
        return $customer;
    }
```